# Override ViewController viewDidLoad method parameter with parameter passed from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

In my `AppDelegate.swift` i am accessing and calling methods from my `ViewController.swift` like this

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShitstuffController") as? ViewController {
    controller.loadViewIfNeeded();
    controller.viewControllerCustomMethod(); // <-- method from ViewController.swift
}
```

and simple calling of method that returns something is working fine, but, in my situation i need to change request url of `WKWebView` what is loaded in `viewDidLoad` method of `ViewController`, and i am trying to achieve it in that way

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShitstuffController") as? ViewController {
    controller.overrideWebViewURL(url: "https://google.com");
    controller.loadViewIfNeeded();
}
```

where `overrideWebViewURL` is a `ViewController` method what looks like that

```
func overrideWebViewURL(url: String) {
    notificationProvidedLink = url;
    isDidLaunchFromNotification = true;

    print(" ----- Link is set");
}
```

Main idea is to call it before calling `controller.loadViewIfNeeded();` in `AppDelegate` to override default url what i load in `viewDidLoad` of `ViewController`, here is full code of logic

```
// AppDelegate.swift
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShitstuffController") as? ViewController {
    controller.overrideWebViewURL(url: link);
    controller.loadViewIfNeeded();
}


//ViewController.swift

var isDidLaunchFromNotification = false
var notificationProvidedLink = "";

func overrideWebViewURL(url: String) {
    notificationProvidedLink = url;
    isDidLaunchFromNotification = true;

    print(" ----- Link is set");
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(" ----- View did load");

    print(isDidLaunchFromNotification);
    print(notificationProvidedLink);

    var url = URL(string: "https://amazon.com");
    if(isDidLaunchFromNotification == true && notificationProvidedLink != "") {
        url = URL(string: notificationProvidedLink);
    }

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!);

    webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    webView.uiDelegate = self;


    print(urlRequest);

    webView.load(urlRequest);
}
```

here is the problem, despite i am actually overriding request url (i can see it by console output), `ViewController` still loads me amazon, instead of google.

Console log is

```
 ----- Link is set
 ----- View did load
true
https://google.com
https://google.com
```

but why? Why it loads "default" url?

Comment: Where do you actually present this view controller?  My guess is that you have one copy of `ViewController` being loaded automatically on start and this one that you modify but never display.

Comment: Em, but how it still prints modified url to console if you are right ? I thought `loadViewIfNeeded` method shows my modified `ViewController`, i actually posted all code what is used for this logic, and i have nothing to add :|

Comment: Added `self.window?.rootViewController = controller;` to `AppDelegate` method end, and it works!! It loads my needed url! I'll check some variants more, and if it works, you helped me!

Comment: That makes sense.  `loadViewIfNeeded` brings the view into memory, but doesn't affect the display.

Comment: Just checked, everything works, if you are interested, you can add `self.window?.rootViewController = controller;` solution as an answer, i ll accept it! :)

Comment: I might be missing something but looking at console output and code - your "default" URL is `https://amazon.com` and it is showing google which is notification URL and is what you need. Anyway `var link: String` with `didSet` and a default value would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do it like that.

Simply add a property to your view controller:

```
var link: String {
    didSet {
        let url = URL(string: link)
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.load(urlRequest)
    }
}
```

In your appDelegate:

```
let viewController = MyViewController()
viewController.link = "www.mylink.com"
```